# Play Integrity checks and reCAPTCHA failed: Missing valid app identifier

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform

I'm encountering an issue with my Android application where I'm getting the following error message: "This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details." Can someone please help me understand the possible causes and suggest a solution for resolving this error?

I have integrated Firebase phone authentication in my android app and I was working fine. since android device verification is deprecated and very app should migrate to google play integrity. when I was implementing the google play integrity API verification getting field and I'm getting error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpNT9.jpg)

I was trying to follow google documentation link given below
[text](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup)

Comment: did u solve this problem? I'm kind of stuck in the same thing and I don't know what's wrong with my app everything was just working fine a month ago